# using bitmap factory to display 150 images at 30 images per second inside a runnable but it's laggy

Tags: java, android, animation, kotlin

I have 150 images in external storage of android device that I've to use as animation for an activity at the rate of 30 images per second.

I've used Bitmap to decode file at the given path and then set it inside an imageView. I am using handler to do this but the animation is quite laggy.

In the code below `animationReadyPath` is the path to the folder and `imageList` is the arraylist of files inside that folder. I used this code inside `onWindowFocusChanged()`.

```
var i = 0
val interval = 1000/30       
val handler = Handler()
val runnable = Runnable {
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval.toLong())
    val imgFile = File(animationReadyPath+imageList[i])
    val myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.absolutePath)
    iv_animation_ready.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)

    if(i<numOfImg){
        i++
    }
    if(i>numOfImg){            
        iv_animation_ready.setImageBitmap(
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                animationReadyPath+imageList[149]
            )
        )
    }
}
handler.postAtTime(runnable, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval)
handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval.toLong())
```

animation is very laggy. How to correct it or suggest other ways to load animations smoothly.

I can't include images inside my project as it'll increase the size of my project.

Comment: Load the images first. Then animate them. Disk I/O and decoding the bitmap will be too slow for 30fps.

Comment: what's the best way to load the images first ?

Answer (score 0):

You should load all images before displaying them. To play the animation, you can use an AnimationDrawable:

```
AnimationDrawable myAnim = new AnimationDrawable();
```

And for each image file, you can use `BitmapFactory` to decode it into a Bitmap and put this Bitmap into a `BitmapDrawable`.

Then you can add this BitmapDrawable to your animation:

```
myAnim.addFrame(myBitmap, 1000/30)
```

You can then use the AnimationDrawable at any time and start the animation with `myAnim.start()`.

Comment: How do I preload the images ?

Comment: @amanchaturvedi just use your own code from above to load the files via BitmapFactory. You can do this in your onCreate for example. Or asynchronous, which is a better approach.

Comment: loading all the images taking a lot of time, it's even hanging my emulator. Please tell me an asynchronous way to add images.

Comment: can you tell how to do that?